# Disqus makes Cufon delay

Tags: cufon, disqus

I'm having a really frustrating problem. I have a [blog](http://scriptish.com), where I use Cufon for post headings. However, I also use Disqus for comments. Disqus adds the javascript it needs directly to the comment-template element, and they seem to load before anything else. This causes a clearly recognizable delay in Cufon taking action.

I have explored the Disqus-plugin source and realized, that the javascript is not being hanged there via a hook (so that it could be unchained and added again to footer), but instead it is directly printed in comments.php. This leaves me with the conclusion that the only solution is to do some javascript-magic?

I'm really hoping someone can help with this issue. Any way to make the Disqus-stuff load after Cufon has initialized? The comments could easily have a 1-second-delay without making a difference in browsing.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen with the [latest Disqus embed code](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal), which is [non-blocking](http://docs.disqus.com/help/100). Can you provide a link to where this is happening?